# 503 Error Service Unavailable error kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I have installed elasticsearch 5.5, logstash 5.5 and kibana 5.5 on same aws ec2 instance for learning purpose. Elasticsearch, logstash and kibana are running but when I open kibana on port 5601 then a default page get open with 503 service error, when I click on management, dev_tools, discovery but every time same page get loaded with 503 error. I am unable to configure elasticsearch with kibana now. I am providing images to show how it behaves

[Kibana Default Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDxQ3.png)

Now when I click on mangement(gear shaped symbol), then it come as

[Kibana management page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Rsc.png)

There is no error or important message found in kibana logs.

I have provided correct elasticsearch server host in kibana.yml, set server.requestTimeout to 2 minutes and provide correct elasticsearch server URL. Still this error is coming.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Do you have X-Pack installed with your elasticsearch? (You can check it by output of `http://<es_url>/_xpack`)

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-46-159:~$ curl http://172.31.46.159/_xpack
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /_xpack was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 172.31.46.159 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
@Oles Savluk